# expression in an string

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to create several directories `"dir_i"` in a mother directory `"home"`. and put an specific file in each directory `"file_j"`. so that I will have `home/dir_1/file_a`, `home/dir_2/file_b`,...

```
Table[CreateDirectory["home/dir_i"],{i,1,10}]
```

obviously doesn't work because `"home/dir_i"` is a string not an expression.

Answer (score 8):

Try this and check for [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToString.html) and [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringJoin.html) (`<>`) in the docs!

```
Table[CreateDirectory[ToFileName[{"C:","Users", "dir_"<>ToString[i]}]], {i, 1, 4}]
```

Use `ToFileName` so the code is platform-independent.